# Spring Security: OAuth2 custom filter to validate password expiration error handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I've been trying to implement OAuth2 password expiration filter and I'm unsure about what the proper way would be to do so. The idea is as follows:

1. User tries to login.
2. User gets response with a header containing token if the password is expired.
3. User get's redirected to password change page using that token (i.e. /password-change/{token}).
4. He submits his old and new passwords, it gets changed.
5. Some rest controller retrieves user id by that token and does the rest password changing logic.
6. User should be redirected back to the initial login page where he logins with his new password (if he would be logged in instantly after the password change, he could navigate through secured pages even if the password would not be changed in background due to some exception, etc.).

So... I set a custom flag in user details for password expiration because I can't use credentialsNonExpired as it gets validated in DaoAuthenticationProvider and thrown as an exception which gets processed as InvalidGrantException which doesn't give me much control. I've figured out that in order to access user details right after it's authentication my filter should be in the inner Spring Security filter chain placed after OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        ...

        http.addFilterAfter(new PasswordExpirationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class
    }
}
```

1. Why does my filter get placed after OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter while there's no BasicAuthenticationFilter in the chain? I've digged through Spring Security and OAuth2 documentation and sources and couldn't find the right answer.
2. If that user's password is expired my filter generates some random string and it saves it to retrieve user details later during the password change request (at least it should be):

   ```
   public class PasswordExpirationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter implements Filter, InitializingBean {

   private static final String TOKEN_HEADER = ...;
   private ExpiredPasswordRepository repo; // gets set in a constructor and is basically holding a concurrent map of tokens

   ...

   protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

       UserDetails details = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

       if (details.isPasswordExpired) {
           String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
           repo.push(uuid, details.getId());

           SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
           SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
           request.getSession(false).invalidate(); // don't create a new session
           response.addHeader(TOKEN_HEADER, uuid);
           response.sendError(HttpStatus.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED, "Credentials have expired");
       } else {
           filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Do I have to revoke the OAuth token as well? It gets reused in later requests and I keep getting the last userDetails object and therefore I keep getting the same response from my filter.

3. Is it even the right place to do all this validation? How should one validate the password for the concrete user and not the OAuth client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I resolved this issue by revoking the access token via injected TokenStore in my filter (I used BearerTokenExtractor to get the token value) which seems pretty logical in this situtation. I still had no time to figure out, why my filter gets placed after OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter, though.

Comment: Oh, and a more appropriate way would be to do this whole expired password validation before obtaining an oauth2 token, I think. I just had to do this quickly and on an already established authentication mechanism.